# BootStrap Error on iOS simulator persisting after restart

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-simulator, bootstrapping

I know it's a duplicate question. But does anyone have a real working solution?

Tried the following but in vain:

1. Restarted simulator: waste of time.
2. Restarted xcode: nothing happened.
3. Restarted system: I hate it, no use.
4. Kill the simulator process from terminal. Still issue persists.

Anyone have ever solved this issue really? Then please share the reason why this is happening and the solution also. NB: No such issue when running in ios device.

Comment: Thanks Hemang. Its not about lot of "reputation", its all about a working solution and you got that. Thanks. +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perform steps from `1-to-5`

**1)** `Reset Simulator (or delete the app which freeze)`

**2)** `Delete project from organizer`

**3)** `Clean / Delete build`

**4)** `Exit Xcode`

**5)** `Restart System`

These would definitely solved this problem.

Comment: I never tried your step 2 before. That worked. Great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This normally happens when more than one instance of the app runs on the simulator(When you repeatedly try to run the app without stopping it). You can try resetting the simulator and cleaning the build in Xcode. Also remember to quit and restart both simulator and Xcode.

Comment: Thanks ACB. Hemang's answer worked.